# Is there any case when the only transaction in Ethercan is IN, but Balance is 0 Ether?

Tags: etherscan

The address that received only a hundred orders of deposit shows in zero balance. 
I understand when using wallet on the exchange, that should have one  transaction that corresponds to OUT. 
But there are no OUT transactions.
Is this possible using a hardware wallet? 
Otherwise, I want to know when this happens.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand the question. Ether never simply appears out of nowhere, it is always sent to the address in some fashion. It doesn't necessarily have to be a traditional transaction, it may be for example a mining fee.

Comment: How about this situation? 
Balance:0 Ether, EtherValue:$0 And Transaction only deposit

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

1. All "in" transactions actually failed to deliver ether.
2. The address is a smart contract that immediately forwards all incoming ether to somewhere else.

Could you show the address you are talking about?